# Singular solution of differential equation $p^2y+2px-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

I have the following differential equation before me for which I am required to find singular solution:

$p^2y+2px-y=0$ where $p=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

On solving it, I got the following general solution:

$y^2=c^2+2cx$

We get $p$-discriminant and $c$-discriminant relation( they turn out to be same in this case) as:

$x^2+y^2=0$

This is a point circle centered at origin. Can it be regarded as singular solution? Our general solution is a family of parabolas and $x^2+y^2=0$ does not touch any of them. Does it mean that for this differential equation, there is no singular solution.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a solution with a general approach to compare your solution against.

Multiply the equation with $y$ to get
$$
y^2 = (2py)x+\frac14(2py)^2.
$$
This is a Clairaut equation for $v=y^2$,
$$
v=v'x+\frac14(v')^2.
$$
The singular solution in $v$ is given via the equation $0=x+\frac12v'$, thus $v'=-2x$ and directly inserted
$$
v=-x^2.
$$
As the part of that with non-negative $v$ is just a point, there is no way to observe the tangency of any curve to it when resolved to the original $y$.

So indeed all you calculated and observed is true.

Comment: Why don't you use integration constant, i.e. $v=C-x^2$?

Comment: Because I insert $v'$ directly into the original equation. Or in other words, only $C=0$ is compatible with the original DE.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, you actually say it in the text.

Answer (score 1):

Let's attack this in a different way.

A differential equation

$F(x,y,p)=0; p\equiv y'$

has a singular solution if and only if such a solution satisfies

$(\partial F/\partial p)_{x,y}=0.$

Here the second equation gives

$2py+2x=0\implies p=-x/y,$

whereupon we back substitute the latter into the original differential equation and and eventually arrive at $x^2+y^2=0$ agreeing with the OP and the other answer.

We actually do have full envelopes in the *complex* domain. With complex variables $x^2+y^2=0\implies y=\pm ix$, and it is easily verified that these complex linear functions do indeed solve the differential equation. On this model the single point $(0,0)$ is the real-variable "shadow" of the complete singular solutions.